# Can not run MongoDB using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed mongoDB in my Ubuntu system but unable to start it.while i am running this `service mongod start` it throwing the following message.

```
start: Unknown job: mongod
```

Here i need to start the MongoDB. Please help me.

Comment: If MongoDB is installed on your system then verify which mongo is working by **which mongo** command if you got a path of mongo then try with these two commands **mongod** or **sudo mongod**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the mongod is not installed properly. Verify this by checking the presence of System V init script in location `/etc/init.d/mongod`. If not present, try installing the mongod again.

Comment: yes,true that is not present. Can you tell me how to install it ?

Comment: MongoDB has already intsalled but mongod is not present. Can you help me ?

Comment: One  of the reason could be that mongo which you have installed is not compatible with ubuntu 14.04. Please follow the steps provided in this documentation page  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. Make sure you follow the steps provided for ubuntu 14.04.